# Samsung SmartTV emulator startup error?

Tags: windows, emulation, samsung-smart-tv

I've just installed the Samsung smarttv SDK and eclipse works fine, but when i click Run Samsung Smart TV Emulator, nothing happens. The first time I ran it it ask me to accept some agreements so i did. Then i tried starting it again but nothing happened. Also when i click on the emulator alone i get an error saying **"The application has failed to start because its side-to-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more information"**

After i got this error i did the sxstrace thing and this is what was shown:

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Emulator2.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Emulator2.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0__6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Auto Servicing Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.7601.17514".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.7601.17514".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_516d712b0f495a45.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4940".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4940".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at G:\User\Software\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package